# CV2 puttext is not adding special characters

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to update text om images using CV2.Puttext feature. Its adding all english words properly but special/asci characters like №,■,<<,etc.. are not added on the image , ?? is added instead of special characters.
Below is the puttext code, i am using cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN font.How can we add above charcters also in image using CV2.puttext ? i know i can use draw.text but i want to add using cv2.puttext only.

```
cv2.putText(img, "■Yes and №",(x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,2.3, (128,128,0), 3)
```

Please share your thoughts on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Hershey fonts are not Unicode.  They don't even have the full ASCII subset.  It was designed for simple annotation, not for sophisticated text processing.  You'll have to use another method.

Comment: ,thanks for the replay, what are the other methods , could u please name any of them.

Comment: PIL (from the `pillow` module) in the `ImageDraw` module can draw text using any TrueType font.  It's easy to convert between OpenCV and PIL.

Comment: draw.text((x, y ),text,font=font,fill=(0,0,0))

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I am trying with below its working but after adding text, image text format issues like text overlapping are occurring, i want to put any text on image dynamically without any text overlapping.
fontpath = 'ArialUnicodeMS.ttf' 
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 25)
draw.text((x, y ),text,font=font,fill=(0,0,0))

Comment: Weil, you have to manage the location of your strings.  You'll need to use `draw.textsize` to find the size of your strings.

Comment: using draw.textsize I am getting width and height of the text, with this I need to change the font  size ?

Comment: I want to get font size for each text line in image and add/replace the text within the same coordinates of the line on imag, i have the coordinates of each text line .

Comment: You can't "replace" existing text unless you know how to restore the background underneath the text.  Remember, in the image, it's not really text.  It's just pixels.

Comment: yes its all pixels, i am able to replace text but in someplace text overlap is happening

Comment: Overlap of the text you are writing?  Horizontally or vertically?

Comment: yes text I am writing is overlapping  horizontally .. i want handle both vertically and  horizontally .. text should be inside the line coordinates only , if text is inside  coordinates then overlapping is not happening .. i reduced font size then its not overlapping but now its not dynamic ... i want to calculate font size based on line coordinates box and text to add on image ,,